# VHDL: problem getting into state

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I've coded this state in VHDL, but I am having problem getting into a certain state.

```
    architecture Behavioral of game is
type LIST  is ARRAY (11 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
Constant LISTEN: LIST := ("0010","0100","1000","0001","0100","0010","0010","0010","1000","0001","0010","0001"); 
begin
process(CLK)
variable prescaler: integer range 0 to 50000000;
Variable control: std_logic := '0';
variable pointer: integer range 0 to 11:=0;
variable test: std_logic:='0';
variable error: std_logic:='0';
variable top_pointer: integer range 0 to 11 := 0;
variable buttontimer:  integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;
begin
if rising_edge (clk) then 
            if control = '0' and error = '0' then 
                winLEd <= "01";
                    if(prescaler < 49999999/1) then     
                        prescaler := prescaler + 1;     
                    else
                        prescaler := 0;
                        top_pointer := top_pointer + 1;  -- Top pointer increment
                        control := '1'; --- trigger event to get to new state
                        --test := '0';
                    end if;
            end if;     
                    if control = '1'  and error = '0' then 
                        winLEd <= "11";
                    --  test := '0';
                        if pointer > (top_pointer) then     -- If pointer is higher than toppointer, it means the sequence has to be incrementet. 
                                LED <= "0000";
                                control := '0';
                                pointer := 0;
                                test := '0';
                                error:= '0';
                        end if;
                        --if switch = "0000" then
                                if switch = LISTEN(pointer-1) and pointer<= top_pointer  then -- Checks if the switch match the sequence. 
                                    test := '1';
                                    buttontimer := buttontimer + 1;
                                    errorLed <= "01";       
                                        if switch = "0000" and test = '1' and buttontimer < 49999999/1 then
                                            pointer:= pointer +1;
                                            test := '0';
                                            errorLed <= "10";   
                                            buttontimer:= 0;
                                        end if; 

                                end if;

                                if switch /= LISTEN(pointer-1) and switch /= "0000"  then  -- if it doesn not match, error will be set high => trigger an new state. 
                                    error:= '1';        
                                end if;     
                                        if switch = "0000"  then                                
                                        Led <= LISTEN(pointer-1);  
                                          errorLed <= "11";
                                            error:= '0';
                                            control := '1';
                                        end if;

                        --end if;   
                    end if; 
                    if error = '1' then  -- stays here infinetly until board is reset. 
                                winLED <=  "10";
                                errorLed <= "00";    
                                Led <= switch;
                    end if; 

end if;                         
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I am having problem incrementing pointer here. Listen is an array, containing  different 4 bit patterns. The Switch is the switches on my FGPA, I've used errorLED to see where I am in code, I see that I am entering this if statement, when the switches mathes the 4 bit pattern.

Comment: Does it work in simulation?

Answer (score 2):

`test` only is 1 when this code is entered:

```
if switch = LISTEN(pointer-1) and pointer<= top_pointer and test = '0' then --  Checks if the switch match the sequence. 
  test := '1';
  buttontimer := buttontimer + 1;
  errorLed <= "01";   
end if;
```

In this if statement, switch has a value of `LISTEN(pointer-1)`. Then further down in the same process, switch needs to be `"0000"` and `test = '1'` in order to hit this code.

```
if switch = "0000" and test = '1' and buttontimer > 1  then
  pointer:= pointer +1;
  test := '0';
  errorLed <= "10";   
  buttontimer:= 0;
end if;
```

So, the above code is only going to be entered when `switch = LISTEN(pointer-1) = "0000"`, and `buttontimer` needs to meet it's requirement too, and `pointer` needs to hit it's requirement too (so that test can be 1).

Another note is that since you reset the value of test to 0 at the beginning of the clock cycle, that the value of test isn't going to carry over from one clock cycle to the next.

```
if control = '1'  and error = '0' then 
  winLEd <= "11";
  Led <= LISTEN(pointer-1);  
  test := '0'; << remove this line
  ...
end if;
```

EDIT:
In order to remember test, in the first block of code, remove the `test := '0'` at the beginning. You are already setting test to zero when the switch is de-asserted.

The FPGA is operating a lot faster than your finger can move. it's going to have run lots of clock cycles between you asserting the switch and de-asserting it. for that reason, you're going to need to remember the value of test, so that when the switch is de-asserted, the FPGA will remember that the switch was pressed. This is why I'm suggesting the removal of the `test := '0'`.

Comment: So you want me to insert it inside first if statement??

Comment: Please look at my edit

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to increment the pointer when what i press is equal to the pattern from the array, if not, it has to set error 1.

Comment: your first try was fine. See my edit.

Comment: Well i've edited my code, where i also have removed test as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. It does exactly the same thing as before.

Comment: are you simulating the code beforehand? I would simulate it, it'll be easier to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I am using the ErrorLED to see where I am in my code.

Comment: is it even possible to simulate it realtime.. since i am triggering the switch.

Comment: you can write a testbench which generates a test switch signal. See http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/VHDLTestbench.pdf and http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-write-testbench.html. Since you have access to all the signals during every clock cycle, it's easier to see exactly where your code is going wrong.

Comment: It looks like i always stay in control = 0, which doesn't make sense since i using the LEd can see I am at control = 1.

Comment: I've realized that i sometimes work, and other times doesn't could be something with button debouncing??

Comment: What about my array, i've wondered why it only works when pointer is pointer-1, i mean how come am i pointing to negative value, when i am starting at 0, and making sure it is zero all the time.